# Swift - Instantiate View Controller in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to have my login page pop up over the initial view controller from the `AppDelegate.swift` and I am using
`let authVC = storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartVC")`
to instantiate it. However, the View Controller is linked to a navigation controller which when I use the code it crashes the app when I click a button the the View Controller. Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        let storybaord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let authVC = storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartVC")
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController?.present(authVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    return true
}
```

In the `Main.Storyboard` file, I have the storyboard ID `("StartVC")` on the first view controller of the Navigation Controller. ScreenShots : http://prntscr.com/lp8fez | 
http://prntscr.com/lp8flq

Heres the crash Log: 

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'toName'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.`

Comment: "it crashes the app" Then show us the crash log, please.

Comment: I think you can't present any controller at launch time!!

Comment: I edited the post and added the crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()
if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
    let storybaord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let authVC = storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartVC")


    window?.rootViewController?= authVC

                 window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
return true
}
```

I’ve used this code and it’s working for me . Try and let me know if more help needed.